# Application works good but while testing, a bean repository isn't created

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

My application starts without errors when I run it normally, but when I run a controller test I receive an error message.

What is the difference between creating beans in an app ran with tests and without them?

Does this happen because of an obvious mistake I made? I attached my code below.

Received error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\quack\IdeaProjects\toucan\target\classes\com\example\toucan\security\SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.toucan.repository.RepositoryNote' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.toucan.repository.RepositoryNote' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    ... 83 more
```

SecurityConfig:

```java
package com.example.toucan.security;

import com.example.toucan.repository.RepositoryNote;
import com.example.toucan.repository.RepositoryUser;
import com.example.toucan.security.filters.FilterNotePermissionProcessor;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final RepositoryNote repositoryNote;
    private final RepositoryUser repositoryUser;

    public SecurityConfig(RepositoryNote repositoryNote, RepositoryUser repositoryUser) {
        this.repositoryNote = repositoryNote;
        this.repositoryUser = repositoryUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        /*
         * For some reason FilterTokenValidator add itself to chain so I've deleted line adding it to filter chain.
         * I left only line adding FilterNotePermissionProcessor and chain works correctly.
         */
        http
            //.addFilterAfter(new FilterTokenValidator(userDetailsServiceImpl), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            //.addFilterAfter(new FilterNotePermissionProcessor(noteDetailsServiceImpl, repositoryNote, userDetailsServiceImpl, repositoryUser), FilterTokenValidator.class);
              .addFilterAfter(new FilterNotePermissionProcessor(repositoryNote, repositoryUser), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    /*@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
    }*/

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /*@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }*/

    //This bean is not necessary but may will be usefull in the future.
    /*@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<FilterSelfProfileActions> filterRegistrationBean() {

        FilterRegistrationBean<FilterSelfProfileActions> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        FilterSelfProfileActions filter = new FilterSelfProfileActions(userDetailsService);

        registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/toucan/user/*", "/toucan/note/*", "/toucan/note");
        return registrationBean;
    }*/
}
```

RepositoryNote:

```java
package com.example.toucan.repository;

import com.example.toucan.model.entity.EntityNote;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface RepositoryNote extends JpaRepository<EntityNote, UUID> {

    EntityNote findByUuid(UUID uuid);

    @Query("SELECT u FROM EntityNote u WHERE u.owner.uuid = :userid ORDER BY u.creationTimestamp DESC")
    List<EntityNote> takeForShortNotes(@Param("userid") UUID userId,
                                       Pageable pageable);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE EntityNote u SET u.title = :title, u.content = :content WHERE u.uuid = :uuid")
    void updateNote(@Param("title") String title,
                        @Param("content") String content,
                        @Param("uuid") UUID uuid);

}
```

ControllerSign:

```java
package com.example.toucan.controller;

import com.example.toucan.model.dto.DtoUsernamePassword;
import com.example.toucan.service.ServiceSign;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ControllerSign {

    private final ServiceSign serviceSign;

    public ControllerSign(ServiceSign serviceSign) {
        this.serviceSign = serviceSign;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String createUser(@Valid @NonNull @RequestBody DtoUsernamePassword dtoUsernamePassword){
        return serviceSign.createUser(dtoUsernamePassword.getUsername(), dtoUsernamePassword.getPassword());
    }

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public String takeToken(@Valid @NonNull @RequestBody DtoUsernamePassword dtoUsernamePassword) {
        return serviceSign.takeToken(dtoUsernamePassword);
    }
}
```

ControllerSignTest:

```java
package com.example.toucan.controller;

import com.example.toucan.ToucanApplication;
import com.example.toucan.model.dto.DtoUsernamePassword;
import com.example.toucan.model.entity.EntityUser;
import com.example.toucan.service.ServiceSign;
import com.example.toucan.util.JwtUtil;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.RestClientTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

//@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ControllerSign.class)
//@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= ToucanApplication.class)
public class ControllerSignTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private ServiceSign serviceSign;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @BeforeEach
    void printApplicationContext() {
        Arrays.stream(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames())
                .map(name -> applicationContext.getBean(name).getClass().getName())
                .sorted()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Test
    public void createUser_valuesOK_statusOK() throws Exception {
        when(serviceSign.createUser(eq("user1"), eq("user1")))
                .thenReturn(jwtUtil.generateToken(new EntityUser("user1", "user1")));

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/signup")
                        .contentType("application/json")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new DtoUsernamePassword("user1", "user1")))
        ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to the ControllerTest the annotatoins of:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerSignTest {
```

Comment: It triggers more errors: Jan 07, 2021 2:01:59 PM org.junit.vintage.engine.descriptor.RunnerTestDescriptor warnAboutUnfilterableRunner
WARNING: Runner org.junit.internal.runners.ErrorReportingRunner (used on class com.example.toucan.controller.ControllerSignTest) does not support filtering and will therefore be run completely.




org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.example.toucan.controller.ControllerSignTest':
  1. No runnable methods

Comment: 1. That seems like a different issue. make sure there are tests in ControllerSignTest. 2. If my answer helped you, will appreciate marking it as such

Comment: Ohhh, it was really obvious mistake. I've imported wrong package (org.junit.jupiter.api.Test instead of org.junit.Test). Thanks D:

Answer (score 1):

`RepositoryNote` and `RepositoryUser` should be also mocked.

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ControllerSign.class)
public class ControllerSignTest {
    @MockBean
    private RepositoryNote repositoryNote;
    @MockBean
    private RepositoryUser repositoryUser;
    // ...
```

see also:

- 4.26.3. Testing Spring Boot Applications

  - [Auto-configured Spring MVC Tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests)
  - [Testing with a mock environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment)

(This test case uses real `JwtUtil`, so maybe it should be run using `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@WebMvcTest`.)

Comment: Ohhh, it was really obvious mistake. I've imported wrong package (org.junit.jupiter.api.Test instead of org.junit.Test). Thanks D: